# Aggregate functions

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains the following information

```
date             sales
2011-02-13        1
2011-02-13        3
2011-02-13        2
2011-02-14        1
2011-02-14        5
2011-02-14        8
2011-02-15        2
etc ...
```

How do I know what is average amount for the period  ?
For example I want to get a result like this one:
Sales are 2,4 per day for period 2011-02-11 - 2011-02-15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select avg(sales) from table where date <= x and date >= y
```

your x and y being the dates e.g.

```
 select avg(sales) from table where date <= '2011-02-15' and date >= '2011-02-11'
```

Comment: the 'where' filters the rows that you are interested in first, then avg, which is an aggregation function, will calculate one result for the remaining set.

Comment: but the problem is that you assumed that there is one line per day which isn the case. I think there is an additional groupby and maybe sum needed anywhere but not sure how exactly.

Comment: Indeed I assumed there was one line per day. I don't think it's a good design to have more than one line per date, the date should at least be key for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

If `` `date` `` is of `DATE` datatype:

```
SELECT SUM(sales) / (1 + DATEDIFF('2011-02-15', '2011-02-11'))
       AS AverageSalesPerDay
FROM TableX 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2011-02-11' 
                 AND '2011-02-15'
```

If it is a `DATETIME` or a `TIMESTAMP`:

```
SELECT SUM(sales) / (DATEDIFF('2011-02-16', '2011-02-11'))
       AS AverageSalesPerDay
FROM TableX 
WHERE `date` >= '2011-02-11' 
  AND `date` <  '2011-02-16'
```